# Does anyone know why the mice package in R gives me an error on different methods?

Tags: r, r-mice

running into an error using the MICE package in R, specifically when using different methods on columns. I've linked the first 100 rows [here](https://github.com/m1ngle/TRCount/blob/main/Test.csv), as the actual dataset is quite extensive. The data has 38 columns of mixed data types, though it's a CDC study so they're all entered as numbers. When I run the simple command

```
imp <- mice(df, print=T)
```

I get a result, but the method of imputation for each column is pmm. However, some are binary some such as education are ordered categorical and some are unordered categorical. I went through and asked mice to use the following imputation methods on each column

```
>meth
    STATE  NUMADULT   GENHLTH  PHYSHLTH  MENTHLTH  HLTHPLN1   MEDCOST  CHECKUP1 
       ""     "pmm" "polyreg"     "pmm"     "pmm"  "logreg"  "logreg" "polyreg" 
 ADDEPEV3   MARITAL     EDUCA  RENTHOM1  VETERAN3   EMPLOY1  CHILDREN   INCOME2 
 "logreg"    "polr" "polyreg"    "polr"  "logreg"    "polr"     "pmm" "polyreg" 
 AVEDRNK3  EXERANY2  FLUSHOT7  HIVRISK5  EYEEXAM1  LCSNUMCG  ACEDEPRS  ACEDRINK 
    "pmm"  "logreg"  "logreg"  "logreg" "polyreg"     "pmm"  "logreg"  "logreg" 
 ACEDRUGS  ACEPRISN  ACEDIVRC  ACEPUNCH  ACEHURT1  ACESWEAR  ACETOUCH      SOMF 
 "logreg"  "logreg"    "polr" "polyreg" "polyreg" "polyreg" "polyreg"    "polr" 
 TRNSGNDR    X_RACE X_AGEG5YR    X_BMI5 X_FRUTSU1 X_VEGESU1 
   "polr"    "polr" "polyreg"     "pmm"     "pmm"     "pmm"
```

When I use the command

```
imp <- mice(LLCP2019forimp, meth = meth, print=T)
```

To tell it to use my selected methods, it goes through exactly 1 imputation with 5 iterations and errors out with this.

Error in colMeans(as.matrix(imp[[j]]), na.rm = TRUE) :
'x' must be numeric

In addition, when I look at the methods actually used,

```
summary(imp)
Class: mids
Number of multiple imputations:  5 
Imputation methods:
    STATE  NUMADULT   GENHLTH  PHYSHLTH  MENTHLTH  HLTHPLN1   MEDCOST  CHECKUP1 
       ""     "pmm"        ""     "pmm"     "pmm"        ""        ""        "" 
 ADDEPEV3   MARITAL     EDUCA  RENTHOM1  VETERAN3   EMPLOY1  CHILDREN   INCOME2 
       ""        ""        ""        ""        ""        ""     "pmm"        "" 
 AVEDRNK3  EXERANY2  FLUSHOT7  HIVRISK5  EYEEXAM1  LCSNUMCG  ACEDEPRS  ACEDRINK 
    "pmm"        ""        ""        ""        ""     "pmm"        ""        "" 
 ACEDRUGS  ACEPRISN  ACEDIVRC  ACEPUNCH  ACEHURT1  ACESWEAR  ACETOUCH      SOMF 
       ""        ""        ""        ""        ""        ""        ""        "" 
 TRNSGNDR    X_RACE X_AGEG5YR    X_BMI5 X_FRUTSU1 X_VEGESU1 
       ""        ""        ""     "pmm"     "pmm"     "pmm"
```

It has only imputed the columns with pmm and ignored the non-numeric data. Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: When I read your data with `read.csv`, columns LCSNUMCG, SOMF, and, TRNSGNDR import as logical values not integer/numeric. Using `colClasses="integer"`fixes that. If that is not the problem, try running subsets of the columns to see if you can narrow down the problem. If that fails, you may have to contact the package maintainer: `maintainer("mice")`.

Comment: Trying your sample data on the first 15 columns I get warnings that ployreg, logreg, and polr are only for categorical data. You probably need to recode those as factors. I still get the same error message you did. For the 100 row sample, LCSNUMCG, SOMF, and TRNSGNDR are missing for all cases.

Comment: Thanks to you both, I needed to convert the columns to factors, or logical data types. The imputation worked flawlessly then